# How to make a foreground NetServer

Tags: perl, soap

The HTTP server detaches from the terminal with `notice: Process Backgrounded`. How to make it stay in foreground?

The code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::Compile::WSDL11;
use XML::Compile::SOAP11;
use XML::Compile::Transport::SOAPHTTP;
use XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::NetServer;

my $daemon  = XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::NetServer->new;

my $wsdl = XML::Compile::WSDL11->new("def.wsdl");

$daemon->printIndex();

$daemon->run(
    name => 'server',
    host => 'localhost',
    port => 7111,
    min_servers => 1,
    max_servers => 1,
    min_spare_servers => 0,
    max_spare_servers => 0);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::NetServer uses [Net::Server](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server.pod) as the server implementation. There is a [configuration option `background` in Net::Server](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Server/lib/Net/Server.pod#background) that seems relevant. It defaults to `undef`, which means *stay in the foreground*.

> Specifies whether or not the server should fork after the bind method to release itself from the command line. Defaults to undef. Process will also background if setsid is set.

When searching for *background* in the docs of XML::Compile::SOAP::Daemon::NetServer you will find the [*Configuration* section](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-Compile-SOAP-Daemon/lib/XML/Compile/SOAP/Daemon/NetServer.pod#Configuration-options), which has a reference to the `background` setting.

> Some general configuration options of Net::Server have a different default. See also the next section about logging.
>
> ```
> Key             Value             New default
> setsid          boolean           true
> background      boolean           true
> ```

So by default, it's set to a true value, and the server will go into the background. That should be easy enough to change.

```
$daemon->run(
    name              => 'server',
    host              => 'localhost',
    port              => 7111,
    min_servers       => 1,
    max_servers       => 1,
    min_spare_servers => 0,
    max_spare_servers => 0,
    background        => 0,             # <------ here
    setsid            => 0,             # <------ and here ("Process will also background if setsid is set")
);
```

Now the server will stay in the frontend, will not fork, and most likely will also only process one request at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Velkan. I didn't see the `setsid` although it was there in the quote. ;)